# Degree of a curve in terms of positive line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth complex algebraic curve and $S$ a smooth complex algebraic surface. Let also
$$
f: C \longrightarrow S
$$

be an holomorphic map. I'm trying to prove that
$$ \deg f(C) = \deg f^* \mathcal{L}$$
for $\mathcal{L}$ a big line bundle.

Comment: What definition of degree are you using for $f(C)$? Also, if things are not projective, neither side will make sense.